# How to build a project via Jenkins from source files to Jar file

Tags: java, jenkins, build

I am new to Jenkins and I am trying to practice it. I have gone through few tutorial for beginner but I think I still miss something, so please help me by pointing me to the right direction.

Assume that I have a Java project with following structure:

Project Folder
src folder:
main
Other classes folder
Lib folder:
lib*jar

I would like to build the project and make a single jar file which includes both src + lib classes.

My question is: How can I use Jenkin to build that single Jar file?

1. How can Jenkins compile whole project?
   I just know the command line to build java files in a single folder, how compile big project in which src file is in different folder. What is command line or best tool people use?
2. How to create jar from the compiled files still they are in different folders?

Can you give me some hint how people build a big project using jenkin, what's tool I have to learn more or some good source/tutorial to solve my issue?

Thank you so much all

Comment: Jenkins cannot do magic. How do you build the project from command line so far? Jenkins can trigger the same and keep the logs with a nice looking GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a gap between your project (that probably gets built and run by some IDE) and automatic builds managed by Jenkins.

Learn about build tools like [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). If they can build your project, Jenkins can trigger them and keep the logs.

Comment: Hi Hiran Chaudhuri,
As I understand all we have it, a git repos + Jenkin
Once we committed a change Jenkins will build, I am unsure which step IDE play the role here
Thanks alot for your comment

Comment: In that case study the logs that Jenkins keeps for each build. You will get to know the details that are necessary. If you need help on that, post such logs.